# writing image data to file in ruby using rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, rmagick

I want to write image to a file using rmagick. Given below is my code

```
im = "base64encodedstring"
image = Magick::Image.from_blob(Base64.decode64(im)
image[0].format = "jpeg"
name ="something_temp"
path = "/somepath/" + name
File.open(path, "wb") { |f|
    f.write(image[0])
}
```

I have also tried to use `f.write(image)`. But what get written in the file is `#<Magick::Image:0x7eff0587f838>`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: As well as Marek's answer, the *reason* why you get the string in the file is because you have called `File.write` which expects a `String` - it converts the supplied to object to a string (I think this is via `.to_s`) and cannot be used to reliably store object data other than `String` types. There are lots of ways to store binary data - in the case of `RMagick`, one way is to use the supplied `read` and `write` methods.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
image[0].write(path)
```

Comment: OP's path does not have type in extension, so you need something like `image[0].write(path) { self.format = "jpeg" }`